# How do I apply anti_join to a list of data.frames using a master data.frame

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frames that have been randomly stratified by class to obtain 70% of the original dataset. I would like to antijoin the list of data.frames to obtain a separate list of data.frames consisting of the remaining 30% of data.

```
require(splitstackshape)

n <- 10
heads <- "bc_title4"

train_split <- function(x) {
  listofdfs <- list()
  for(i in 1:n){
    df <- stratified(x, 1, 0.7)
    listofdfs[[i]] <- df
  }
  return(listofdfs)
}

train_list <- train_split(survey_points) #returns data.frame list to environment

test_split <- function(x) {
  listofdfs2 <- list()
  for(i in train_list){
    df <- x[!x$id %in% data.frame(train_list[i])$id,]
    listofdfs2[[i]] <- df
  }
  return(listofdfs2)
}

test_list <- test_split(survey_points)
```

However I do not know how to write a function for the antijoin as I get the following error:

```
Error in train_list[i] : invalid subscript type 'list' 
6.
data.frame(train_list[i]) 
5.
x$id %in% data.frame(train_list[i])$id 
4.
x$id %in% data.frame(train_list[i])$id 
3.
`[.data.frame`(x, !x$id %in% data.frame(train_list[i])$id, ) 
2.
x[!x$id %in% data.frame(train_list[i])$id, ] 
1.
test_split(survey_points)
```

The same error when attempting to use the function anti_join:

```
test_split <- function(x) {
  listofdfs2 <- list()
  for(i in train_list){
    anti_join(x, data.frame(train_list[i]), by = "id")
    listofdfs2[[i]]
  }
  return(listofdfs2)
}


test <- test_split(survey_points)
 Error in train_list[i] : invalid subscript type 'list' 
9.
data.frame(train_list[i]) 
8.
tbl_vars(y) 
7.
check_valid_names(tbl_vars(y), warn_only = TRUE) 
6.
anti_join.tbl_df(tbl_df(x), y, by = by, copy = copy, ...) 
5.
anti_join(tbl_df(x), y, by = by, copy = copy, ...) 
4.
as.data.frame(anti_join(tbl_df(x), y, by = by, copy = copy, ...)) 
3.
anti_join.data.frame(x, data.frame(train_list[i]), by = "id") 
2.
anti_join(x, data.frame(train_list[i]), by = "id") 
1.
test_split(survey_points)
```

Comment: What is the code you run to get that error? I don't see an `anti_join` attempt... did you do something like `lapply(test_list, function(x) anti_join(survey_points, x))`?

Comment: `setdiff` might be a better approach, `dplyr::setdiff` works well on data frames. (Though if we're talking better approaches, keeping track of row indices is a better way to do this --- you won't run into problems like this one and you don't have to copy your data for every fold.)

Comment: The error comes from the code: `test_list <- test_split(survey_points)`

Comment: Okay, try my version: `test_list = lapply(train_list, function(x) anti_join(survey_points, x))`. As for what's wrong in yours, at a glance I think you need to be using `train_list[[i]]` not `train_list[i]`. And you need to assign it. Saying `1 + 1; x` doesn't assign 2 to x, your for loop should be `listofdfs2[[i]] <- anti_join(...)`. And it's strange to me that you pass in the original data frame as an argument `x` but you don't pass in `train_list`. Usually we try to pass in everything.

Comment: (Nothing tested. If you want help testing, make your example reproducible by providing a little sample data or using built-in data like `mtcars`.)

Comment: thank you your version `test_list = lapply(train_list, function(x) anti_join(survey_points, x))` worked perfectly. Thanks again for your time and patience.